# Control does not go to expected line in angularjs controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Can someone please tell me what is the problem with this angularjs controller?
the part from " var userData "  does not have an effect in the browser.
if i write an alert before it ,there is no alert box when page loads.May be I am missing something.

```
angular.module('gbuyRef').controller('HomeController', function ($scope, $window, $http, $cookies) {
'use strict';
            $scope.fName =  $cookies.fName;
            $scope.init = function () {
            var  data = "[{ \"productId\" : \"9970QYPMNAUUI\", \"productName\" : \"Micca Speck 1080p Full-HD Ultra Portable\", \"imageUrl\" : \"../../s3/images/99738A3AY55HN_resized.jpg\" }]";

                    $scope.products = JSON.parse(data);

                    var products_page = [];
                    var products_pages = [];
                    var count = 4;

                    $scope.products_pages = products_pages;

                    for(var i=4;i<$scope.products.length;i++){
                        if(count > 1){
                        products_page.push($scope.products[i]);
                        count--;
                        if($scope.products.length === i+1){
                            products_pages.push(products_page);
                            return;
                        }
                    } else{
                        products_page.push($scope.products[i]);
                        products_pages.push(products_page);
                        products_page = [];
                        count = 4;
                    }
                }


             var  userData = "[{ \"productId\" : \"9970DLXEVOQ01\", \"productName\" : \"Google Chromecast\", \"imageUrl\" : \"../../s3/images/9973GRKFEWUU1_resized.jpg\" }]";
                $scope.userList = JSON.parse(userData);

                var user_products_page = [];
                var user_products_pages = [];
                var count_1 = 4;

                $scope.user_products_pages = user_products_pages;

                for(var j=4;j<$scope.userList.length;j++){
                    if(count_1 > 1){
                        user_products_page.push($scope.userList[j]);
                        count_1--;
                        if($scope.userList.length === j+1){
                            user_products_pages.push(user_products_page);
                            return;
                        }
                    }else{
                        user_products_page.push($scope.userList[j]);
                        user_products_pages.push(user_products_page);
                        user_products_page = [];
                        count_1 = 4;
                    }
                }   
            }


            $scope.logOut = function() {
                $cookies.fName = "";
                $window.location.href="/static/html/login.html";
            }
        });
```

Here is the html:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en" ng-app="gbuy">
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Gbuy-Product Details</title>

        <!-- Bootstrap -->
        <link href="../css/external/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="../css/gbuy/gbuy.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Patua+One' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <script src="../js/external/bootstrap/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
        <script src="../js/external/jquery-ui/ui/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <script src="../js/external/bootstrap/bootstrap.js"></script>  
        <script src="../js/external/angular/angular.js"></script>
        <script src="../js/external/angular/angular-cookies.js"></script>
        <script src="../js/gbuy/gbuy.js"></script>
        <script src="../js/gbuy/gbuy-ang-controller-test.js"></script>
        <script src="../js/gbuy/gbuy-ang-directives.js"></script>
        <script src="../js/external/angular/angular-cookies.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(function() {
                $('#carousel_home').carousel();
            });
            $(function() {
                $('#carousel_user').carousel();
            });
            $('.carousel .item').each(function(){
                var next = $(this).next();
                if (!next.length) {
                  next = $(this).siblings(':first');
                }
                next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));

                if (next.next().length>0) {
                  next.next().children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
                }
                else {
                  $(this).siblings(':first').children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
                }
            });

        </script>
      </head>
        <body  ng-controller="HomeController" ng-init="init()">
          <div class="col-xs-11" style="width:700pt; height:150pt; margin-top:5px; ">
            <div class="row " style="margin-left:75pt;">
              <label class="text-center" style="margin-top:10pt;font-size:14pt;">Highlighted Deals</label>
            </div>
            <div id ="carousel_home" class="carousel slide " >
              <div class="carousel-inner text-center" style="margin-left:75px;">

                <div class="item active">
                  <div class="col-xs-3 " style="margin-right:-50px;" ng-repeat="(key, value) in products.slice(0, 4) track by $index">
                   <img src= {{value.imageUrl}} alt="No Image"/>
                   <a href="#"><h6>{{value.productName}}</h6></a>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item" ng-repeat="page in products_pages">
                  <div class="col-xs-3 " style="margin-right:-50px;" ng-repeat="image in page">
                    <img  src= {{image.imageUrl}} alt="No Image" />
                    <a href="#"><h6>{{image.productName}}</h6></a>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div> <!--End of carousel-inner-->
              <a class="left carousel-control pull-left" href="#carousel_home" data-slide="prev"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></i></a>
              <a class="right carousel-control pull-right" href="#carousel_home" data-slide="next"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></a>
            </div><!--End of carousel_home-->
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-11" style="width:700pt; height:500pt; margin-top:5px; ">
            <div class="row " style="margin-left:75pt;">
              <label class="text-center" style="margin-top:10pt;font-size:14pt;">Recommended Deals</label>
            </div>
            <div id ="carousel_user" class="carousel slide " >
              <div class="carousel-inner text-center" style="margin-left:75px;">

                <div class="item active">
                  <div class="col-xs-3 " style="margin-right:-50px;" ng-repeat="(key, value) in userList.slice(0, 4) track by $index">
                   <img src= {{value.imageUrl}} alt="No Image"/>
                   <a href="#"><h6>{{value.productName}}</h6></a>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item" ng-repeat="page in user_products_pages">
                  <div class="col-xs-3 " style="margin-right:-50px;" ng-repeat="image in page">
                    <img  src= {{image.imageUrl}} alt="No Image" />
                    <a href="#"><h6>{{image.productName}}</h6></a>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div> <!--End of carousel-inner-->
              <a class="left carousel-control pull-left" href="#carousel_user" data-slide="prev"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></i></a>
              <a class="right carousel-control pull-right" href="#carousel_user" data-slide="next"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></a>
            </div><!--End of carousel_user-->
        </div>
        </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: You do have `ng-init='init()'` directive in your view? You also need to inject the scope, window and all the rest. Is this handled somewhere else?

Comment: Also, do you have ng-controller="HomeController" anywhere?

Comment: We need to see your html as well.

Comment: I have added the html. The things is that the first carousel is getting loaded with the items but the second is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it, I have a return statement in first for loop's second. Hence controller returns from there.